# Why is there a difference in my SQL output

Tags: t-sql, pivot, sql-order-by

This is puzzling me no end, and I know it might be tough without the data but thought it might be a longshot to post here.

Here goes, the first code I received was this

```
USE [Radiotherapy]
GO

if exists (
    select  * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    where o.xtype in ('U') 

   and o.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#MySampleTemp')
)
DROP TABLE #MySampleTemp;

if exists (
    select  * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    where o.xtype in ('U') 

   and o.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#MyPivotTemp')
)
DROP TABLE #MyPivotTemp;

SELECT [AttendanceNumber]
      ,CASE WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 6 AND 18 THEN '6-18'
        WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 19 AND 150 THEN '19+'
        ELSE 'Error' END AS AgeRange
      ,[LocalPatientIdentifier]
      ,[ExaminationDate]
      ,[ExamExaminationCode] INTO #MySampleTemp
FROM [dbo].[tblRadiologyData] 
WHERE AttendanceSiteCode IN('CNM','RNM')
--AND AttendanceStatus NOT IN ( 'Appt', 'Booked In', 'Cancelled', 'Pending' )
--AND AttendancePatientGroup = 'Out Patient'
--AND AttendancePatientCategory IN ( 'EU', 'Military', 'N.H.S.' ) 
--AND AttendanceSourceName <> 'PACs Support'
AND [ExaminationDate] >= '1 OCTOBER 2015' -- 

ORDER BY [AttendanceNumber], CASE WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 6 AND 18 THEN '6-18'
        WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 19 AND 150 THEN '19+'
        ELSE 'Error' END, [LocalPatientIdentifier], [ExaminationDate], ExamExaminationCode

SELECT [AttendanceNumber],AgeRange,[LocalPatientIdentifier],[ExaminationDate], 1 AS ExamCount,
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14] INTO #MyPivotTemp
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [AttendanceNumber] 
    ORDER BY [AttendanceNumber], [LocalPatientIdentifier]) rn
  FROM #MySampleTemp
) AS st
pivot
(
  MAX(ExamExaminationCode)
  FOR rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14])
) AS pivottable

SELECT 
[1] AS Exam01,
[2] AS Exam02,
[3] AS Exam03,
[4] AS Exam04,
[5] AS Exam05,
[6] AS Exam06,
[7] AS Exam07,
[8] AS Exam08,
[9] AS Exam09,
[10] AS Exam10,
[11] AS Exam11,
[12] AS Exam12,
[13] AS Exam13,
[14] AS Exam14,
COUNT(ExamCount) AS [No. Attendances]
FROM #MyPivotTemp
GROUP BY [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14]
ORDER BY [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14]
```

What I tried to do was replicate this in query as follows:

USE [Radiotherapy]

```
;With CTE AS (SELECT s.attendanceNumber,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 3 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 4 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 5 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 6 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode6,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 7 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode7,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 8 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode8,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 9 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode9,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 10 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode10,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 11 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode11,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 12 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode12,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 13 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode13,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 14 THEN s.ExamExaminationCode END) as examCode14
FROM (
    SELECT  [AttendanceNumber]
           ,[ExaminationDate]
           ,[ExamExaminationCode]
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [AttendanceNumber] 
            ORDER BY [RadiologyID]) as rnk --Ordered by date ASC 

      FROM [Radiotherapy].[dbo].[tblRadiologyData] rd 
      where rd.ExaminationDate >= '01 october 2015'
      and   rd.AttendanceSiteCode IN('CNM','RNM') ) s
GROUP BY s.attendanceNumber)

Select CTE.examCode1,
         CTE.examCode2,
         CTE.examCode3,
         CTE.examCode4,
         CTE.examCode5,
         CTE.examCode6,
         CTE.examCode7,
         CTE.examCode8,
         CTE.examCode9,
         CTE.examCode10,
         CTE.examCode11,
         CTE.examCode12,
         CTE.examCode13,
         CTE.examCode14,
         COUNT(CTE.AttendanceNumber) as [No of occurances]
from CTE
GROUP by CTE.examCode1,
         CTE.examCode2,
         CTE.examCode3,
         CTE.examCode4,
         CTE.examCode5,
         CTE.examCode6,
         CTE.examCode7,
         CTE.examCode8,
         CTE.examCode9,
         CTE.examCode10,
         CTE.examCode11,
         CTE.examCode12,
         CTE.examCode13,
         CTE.examCode14

ORDER BY CTE.examCode1
```

Great I thought until my code returned more results which puzzled me. Having broken it down I found the offending code from the original query:

```
ORDER BY [AttendanceNumber], CASE WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 6 AND 18 THEN '6-18'
        WHEN AgeAtExamDate BETWEEN 19 AND 150 THEN '19+'
        ELSE 'Error' END, [LocalPatientIdentifier], [ExaminationDate], ExamExaminationCode
```

When I removed this from the first query the results matched, but my question is how and why is an `ORDER BY` affecting the output. I assumed this was just showing how the results are ordered? Understanding why code is doing what it's doing is something I really need to get my head around. Any advise more than welcome.

Comment: Impossible to tell exactly, but from the first glance it should not change the count of result set.

Comment: but it does, I've just ran it again, firstly with the ORDER BY bit returning 300 results then I removed it and only 71 results, this is why I'm baffled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it have something to do with this piece of code:

```
SELECT *,
       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [AttendanceNumber] 
ORDER BY [AttendanceNumber], [LocalPatientIdentifier]) rn
FROM #MySampleTemp
```

Obviously your ordering is not breaking a tie(it isn't deterministic) and it produces rank number differently when you have ordered data in temp table and when not ordered. Try to add some `PK` to your temp table so the above code will look like:

```
SELECT *,
       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [AttendanceNumber] 
ORDER BY [AttendanceNumber], [LocalPatientIdentifier], [SomePK]) rn
FROM #MySampleTemp
```

Then removing ordering from first select statement will not have an effect on the result set.